# Setting a cookie based on query string for split testing

Tags: mod-rewrite

If a query string is detected, I want to update/set a cookie so a particular dir is used for that browser session or until the query string is explicitly set again. Visitor is not to see the dir, but instead will just see `http://mydomain.com/`.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work as expected. Pretty sure I'm writing the logic wrong, but not sure where.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} splittest=(A|B)
RewriteRule splittest=(A|B) [CO=splittest:$1:%{HTTP_HOST}:0:/,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} splittest=A [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} splittest=A

# Split test A
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ A/$1 [L]
# Split test B
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ B/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I'm assuming your `.htaccess` is located at web root `/` directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} splittest=A [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=splittest:A:%{HTTP_HOST}:0:/]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} splittest=B [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=splittest:B:%{HTTP_HOST}:0:/]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} splittest=A [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} splittest=A [NC]
# Split test A
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ A/$1 [L]
# Split test B
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ B/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried accessing `http://mydomain.com/?splittest=B` and all I get is the error `You don't have permission to access /A/[CO=splittest:B:mydomain.com:0:/] on this server.`

Comment: Ah, sorry missed the `-` before `CO`. Please, try again.

Comment: No more error, but `A` always loads even if I specify `splittest=B`, which is what I was getting before.

Comment: @EcomEvo, it's not possible to do the capture from the query string and substitute the CO value directly. So, you need two [CO] rules.

Comment: @EcomEvo Glad to know it's finally working. Don't I deserve a +1 for persistence? :)

Comment: +1 for persistence! :) One final thing though, I just realized this is preventing me from accessing scripts outside the A and B dirs. How can I exclude rewriting for those?

Comment: @EcomEvo, say, you want to exclude `/C` and `/D` from redirection. Add another condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(C|D)(/.*)?$ [NC]` to the rule.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Would give you +2 if I could! Thanks again!

Comment: OK, so I've run into a problem with this. Works beautifully on my Apache 2.4 local server but fails utterly on our 2.2.25 live server. Could something about this be incompatible with the older version and how to fix?

Comment: Nevermind, figured this one out as well! Apache 2.4 will treat expire=0 as meaning until browser session ends. Apache 2.2.25 needs a value greater than 0 or it expires immediately.